# Is a "SIMD Queue" possible?

Tags: graphics, sse, simd

Excuse me that I do not know the exactly glossary.

What I want to implement is a queue-like SIMD container.

Imagine that I use SIMD to do packed ray marching, that is, there are four rays marching the distance field at a time. 
There is a possibility that two of the rays first hit the object,  then I want to extract them from the current SIMD register and fetch another two ray ID in the register.

I find great difficulties in combining one Ray ID with a remain 3-Ray-ID-tuple register, because SIMD's shuffle operations do not work this way.

Making use of some bit shifting/bit masking operations is a solution, but I want to hear whether there is another elegant approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really how SIMD works, sorry.

You can run 4 identical calculations in parallel no problem.

However, there is already a bit of a problem with sampling the height field in your ray marching. 4 different rays will need different samples at a time, unless it is a very very contrieved special case (parallel rays, spaced at exactly 1 texel offset, and parallel to either *u* or *v*). In other words, you need a gather operation.

Most current architectures (you did not specify one) don't support scatter/gather, such as e.g. reading 4 arbitrary locations from a height map into one SIMD register. You can of course do it, but it will be 4 reads and 4 shuffles and it will be slower than just skipping SIMD alltogether.

You also cannot easily swap in and out arbitrary data at arbitrary times, and continue with some other code in one half of the SIMD register while doing something different (the first part of the calculation) on the other half. *SIMD just doesn't work that way*.
In SIMD operation, all data executes the same instructions at the same time (or rather, the instruction only executes once, but on "multiple pieces of data"). Also, SIMD and branching is kind of "no go". Not only is branching inefficient, but it also affects every piece of data, not only the ones you want.
If anything, one uses conditional moves with SIMD, or one just continues the calculation with the whole lot.

Comment: I think you are mostly true @Damon, except with masking/andps, shufps, etc one can add new data to only 1, half, or 3 segments of the xmm_ data elements.

Comment: @tomByrer Most shuffle instructions (except `PSHUFB` and the AVX ones)   and insertion instructions require the permutation mask or insertion position to be "immediate" value, which means hard-coding. There will need to be branches in your code if the permutation or insertion position is determined at runtime.

Comment: @tomByrer: Yes, you can use masking/and/shuffle to extract parts of a SIMD register, and you can insert new data too. But it's not efficient to begin with, and you still must execute the exact same operations on the entire register henceforth. This means you can only ever do it between iterations (not _generally_ possible, only possible with some tasks/algorithms). If done with some care, this will work for some algorithms, but in any case it is considerable overhead which kills the benefits of using SIMD at all, and it is not straightforward, easily maintainable code. It is much easier and...

Comment: ... more efficient to just run the whole batch even if half of the register is done with calculations already. Or, especially in the light of the gather problem, not do SIMD at all. Really... SIMD is great _when the shoe fits_, but it is no good otherwise (this applies to most techniques and tools).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered other SSE commands to load only the low or high elements?

```
movss: copy a single floating-point data
movlps: copy 2 floating-point data (low packed)
movhps: copy 2 floating-point data (high packed)
movaps: copy aligned 4 floating-point data (fast)
movups: copy unaligned 4 floating-point data (slow)
movhlps: copy 2 high elements to low position
movlhps: copy 2 low elements to high position
```

http://www.songho.ca/misc/sse/sse.html

Or if you want to use SHUFPS, I can export a Windows .exe tool that can help wrap your mind around all the shuffling possibilities.

Also, look into [AVX SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions); it is only available on the newest Intel & AMD CPUs, but allows 8 32bit float data elements to be processed at once.